# Numpy empty list type inference

Tags: python, numpy

Why is the empty list `[]` being inferred as float type when using `np.append`?

```
np.append([1,2,3], [0])
# output: array([1, 2, 3, 0]), dtype = np.int64

np.append([1,2,3], [])
# output: array([1., 2., 3.]), dtype = np.float64
```

This is persistent even when using a `np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int32)` as `arr`.

It's not possible to specify a dtype for append, so I am just curious on why this happens. Numpy's concatenate does the same thing, but when I try to specify the dtype I get an error:

```
np.concatenate([[1,2,3], []], dtype=np.int64)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

But finally if I set the unsafe casting rule it works:

```
np.concatenate([[1,2,3], []], dtype=np.int64, casting='unsafe')
```

Why is `[]` considered a float?

Comment: It's not `[]` that's treated as a `float`. An array needs to know what type to use for the elements. It tries to infer this from the contents of the base list, but when the list is empty, there's nothing to base an inference on. In that case, `np.float64` is chosen.

Comment: I just found another workaround - if it works for you: `append(a, array([], int))`. But the *why* I cannot answer either.

Comment: @Dr.V Yes, replacing ```[]``` with ```np.array([], int)``` is a good solution, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.append` is subject to *well-defined semantic rules* like any Numpy binary operation. As a result, it first converts the input operands to Numpy arrays if this is not the case (typically with `np.array`) and then apply the semantic rules to find the type of the resulting array and check it is a valid operation before applying the actual operation (here the concatenation). The array type returned by [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) is "determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence" regarding to the documentation. When the list is empty, like in your case, the default type is `numpy.float64` as stated in the documentation of [`np.empty`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty). This *arbitrary choice* was made long ago and has not been changed since in order not to break old codes. Please note that It seems not all Numpy developers agree with the current choice and so this is a matter of debate. For more information, you can read [this opened issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10405).

The rule of thumb is to use either existing Numpy arrays or to perform an explicit conversion to a Numpy array using `np.array` with a fixed `dtype` parameter (as described in the above comments).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for `np.append` (via docs link or `ipython`):

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

The first argument is turned into an array, if it isn't one already.

You don't specify the axis, so both `arr` and `values` are ravelled - turned into 1d array.  `np.ravel` is also python code, and does `asanyarray(a).ravel(order=order)`

So the dtype inference is done by `np.asanyarray`.

The rest of the action is `np.concatenate`.  It too will convert the inputs to arrays if necessary.  The result dtype is the "highest" of the inputs.

`np.append` is a poorly conceived (IMO) alternative way of using `np.concatenate`.  It is not a list append clone.

Also be careful about "empty" arrays:

```
In [73]: np.array([])
Out[73]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [74]: np.empty((0))
Out[74]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [75]: np.empty((0),int)
Out[75]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

The common list idiom

```
alist = []
for i in range(10):
    alist.append(i)
```

does not translate well into `numpy`.  Build a list of arrays, and do one `concatenate/vstack` at the end.  Don't iterate over "empty" arrays, however created.

Comment: I didn't know you could inspect the source code with ipython, that's really neat and would save me a lot of time lol.